# Rails routes.rb use get to add suffix to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to figure out how can i build this route in rails:

```
resources :cases do
  resource :profile do
    get 'regions', :to => "cases#regions"
  end
end
```

This code will generate method **case_regions_profile_path**, but i want it upside down: **case_profile_regions_path**, is it possible using get 'rule'? I just want to point this path to a controller with specific action.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its typo you have used `resource` instead of `resources` for `profiles`

```
resources :cases do
  resources :profile do
    get 'regions', :to => "cases#regions"
  end
end
```

This generates:

```
case_profile_regions GET  /cases/:case_id/profile/:profile_id/regions(.:format) cases#regions
```

Comment: in my case it should be a:
get 'profile/regions'
i use many of this matches and profile resource will be repeated:
get 'profile/regions'
get 'profile/associates'
..... etc
i was searching for some more elegant (short) solution

Comment: I've updated question, there was another parent route rule, and with this solution i'm getting profile_case_regions_path.